# gdb - how to see what function used stdout?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have an OpenGL library bug I'm trying to trace, and the bug prints out something that looks like C code into stdout. [This is the program](http://pastie.org/6214339), and the bug occurs as soon as `glutMainLoop()` is called, but I suspect that it's not that function that is faulty. How would I go tracing what function wrote to stdout?

As per request, the output:

```
arc_ccw_turn, p = 0
case b
arc_ccw_turn, p = 0
case d
arc_ccw_turn, p = 0
case a
arc_ccw_turn, p = 0
case c
```

I've [reported the bug already](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61003), but I'd try and provide a GDB backtrace for the issue too.

Comment: Can you show us that weird output that looks like C code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Linux then set a breakpoint on `write()`, all output to `stdout` and `stderr` eventually goes through this function. The following is for `x86-64`, for other architectures you would need to change register names:

```
$ gdb /usr/bin/cat
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/cat...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) set args /proc/cpuinfo
(gdb) b write
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401740
(gdb) condition 1 ($rdi == 1 || $rdi == 2)
(gdb) display $rdi
(gdb) display $rsi
(gdb) display $rdx
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/cat /proc/cpuinfo
3: $rdx = 3368
2: $rsi = 6348800
1: $rdi = 1
(gdb) p (char*)$rsi
$4 = 0x60e000 "processor\t: 0\nvendor_id\t: GenuineIntel\ncpu family\t: 6\nmodel\t\t: 30\nmodel name\t: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         870  @ 2.93GHz\nstepping\t: 5\nmicrocode\t: 0x5\ncpu MHz\t\t: 1199.000\ncache size\t: 8192 KB\nphy"...
```

Comment: This does help, I can see write being called with the above text, but how can I get the function that called write?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to trace the function.

Answer (score 1):

Put breakpoints on `std::streambuf::sputc` and `std::streambuf::sputn`.  If necessary, do `print std::cin::rdbuf()` once you're in `main`, and condition the break point on `this` being equal to the value use get back from this expression.

Comment: +1, but this won't catch `printf`'s, right? GLUT may well use those.

Comment: Hmm, I think this may be a bit too hard for me. I tried doing a `break` on those two, but doesn't really help..

Comment: @us2012 Good point.  It might also use `puts`, `fputs` or even `putchar` (which is usually implemented as a macro).  I suppose you could open up `stdio.h`, figure out what it does, and set your break points there.  (Or just find an alternative library that does things correctly.)